# CKEDITOR - insert html text or img on click on some DIV outside CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, insert, ckeditor

I have CKEDITOR running on webpage.
I would like to have few BUTTONS outside CKEDITOR (in other area of webpage) ( or DIV-s, A href etc) which after click will add some html to CKEDITOR.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

im not sure what you mean, im new to html but i have quite a few notes in it which help me if you can explain what you want done properly or a picutre with an example maybe I could be of more help

Comment: Uploaded here: https://ibb.co/WBhtJfJ

I want to bind jquery action to these three green buttons...
After click on green button I want script to insert HTML into CKEditor